# Keeping QPlainTextEdit as small as possible without needing a scroll bar

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qt5

I have a `QPlainTextEdit` that will contain varying amounts of text - sometimes nothing at all, sometimes so much that it will wrap around a couple dozen times.  I would like to keep the `QPlainTextEdit` only as tall as necessary to keep all of its contents visible.  There should be no empty lines unless it is entirely empty.

I have tried setting the size policy to `Minimum` and `MinimumExpanding`, and setting the minimum and maximum heights to zero.  No combinations of these works; in all cases, an empty `QPlainTextEdit` will be about four and a half lines tall.

The only thing that seems to reduce the height below this 4.5-line limit is `setFixedHeight`.  However if I do this then I will somehow need to calculate the required height myself, which kind of ruins the point of using a library in the first place.

Right now, the only option I can think of that might work reasonably well is something like this:

```
def onResize_or_textChanged(...):
  my_text_edit.setHeight(0)
  while my_text_exit has a visible scroll bar:
    my_text_edit.setHeight(my_text_edit.height() + 1)
```

Which is pretty clearly a rather hacky solution.

**How can I make a `QPlainTextEdit` maintain the minimum height necessary to fully display its text?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to calculate the minimum height so that all `QTextBlock`s are visible using `blockBoundingGeometry()`:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.te = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit()
        self.te.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.te.updateRequest.connect(self.handle_updateRequest)
        self.handle_updateRequest()

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        lay.addWidget(self.te, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        self.resize(640, 480)

    def handle_updateRequest(self):
        doc = self.te.document()
        tb = doc.findBlockByNumber(doc.blockCount() - 1)
        h = self.te.blockBoundingGeometry(tb).bottom() + 2 * doc.documentMargin()
        self.te.setFixedHeight(h)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: `blockBoundingGeometry()` fails to find the correct height if contents are set using `appendHtml()` in Qt4 for some reason